# file is encrypted or is not a database , QT

Tags: database, qt, sqlite

Sorry for posting this even though there're a few posts about this , but they're not helping.

I'm using sqlite with QT , I wanted to do a simple query but it gives me this error:

file is encrypted or is not a database Unable to execute statement

Some posts' comments say that the DB may be corrupt, I used another program and created a test table from scratch and still has the same problem, this is the code:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("AdmissionTestDB.sql");
    db.open();
    if(db.isOpen())
    {
        QSqlQuery q = db.exec("SELECT * FROM USERS");
        if(!q.lastError().isValid())
        {
            qDebug()<<"works!";
            while(q.next())
            {
                qDebug()<<q.value(8).toString();
            }
        }
        else
            qDebug()<<"---db failed to open! , error: "<<q.lastError().text();

        db.close();
        return true;
    }
    qDebug()<<"db failed to open! , error: "<<db.lastError().text();
    return false;
```

More Information hopefully it would help solving this:

1- I'm using SQLITE 3
2- The problem happens when I use `QSqlQuery q = db.exec("SELECT * FROM USERS");` so the DB actually opens!
3- I used two GUI programs to create the DB one of them is the latest version of SQLiteStudio which is version 3.0.4

Comment: So did it fail to open the DB or fail to execute the statement?

Comment: @cmannett85 The DB opens just fine , and it enters the first if , but the problem is when I execute.

Comment: @user3504658 Your db is sqlite 2 or 3 ?

Comment: @user4757345 , SQLITE 3 and I used two programs to create a table and I got the same problem when I tested them on QT.

Comment: Can you add your table's DDL to your question? Maybe you use some syntax that is not supported by SQLite driver version embedded in Qt.

Comment: @Googie I'm not sure what you mean ? I'm new to databases and I only used it since it was required, I used "SQLiteStudio 3.0.4" to create a sqlite 3 database with a single table.

Comment: The DDL here is the `CREATE TABLE` statement of your table. In SQLiteStudio just open table and you will have "DDL" tab on top.

Comment: @Googie OK i'm so sorry for wasting your time , in turns out exporting the DB will not work in QT , I had to the same file that the SQLiteStudio is using in order to work, but why put export option if it's going to be like this ?

Comment: Exporting is exporting to different format. If you want to use database created in SQLiteStudio (or any other tool like this), just point the `QSqlDatabase` to the **actual database file**. That's the one you choose in SQliteStudio in "Add database" or "Edit database" dialog.